# Getting attributes of calling methods

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a library where the entry points methods are labeled with some attribute. The internal methods need to know whether the original attribute on the entry point has a value of `1`, `2`, `3` ...

```
[MyAttribute(1)]
public void Method1() {
    InternalMethod();
}

[MyAttribute(2)]
public void Method2() {
    InternalMethod();
}

[MyAttribute(3)]
public void Method3() {
    InternalMethod();
}
```

The only way that I know to get the attribute is to traverse the stack up to the root and search for a method that has the `MyAttribute` attribute. The problem with this approach is that I am implementing it using the `StackTrace` class, which is too expensive as the methods are called during frequent `HTTP` requests that need to be as fast as possible.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Its a strange requirement, but yeah, `StackFrame` is the obvious solution .

Answer (score 2):

Pass the number to the `InternalMethod` as argument.

Comment: Neat and simple, yehaa

Comment: @TheGeneral not really.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that:

- Your current stack traversal route works
- You really don't want to do this explicitly as per TcKs's answer
- You make calls from a relatively small number of places
- Any particular direct call site to `InternalMethod` would only have one attribute in its stack trace (you don't have multiple calls from different places that then call `InternalMethod()` with different attribute values elsewhere in the stack)

If those assumptions are true, I have a pretty hacky suggestion...

Change the `InternalMethod` signature to

```
void InternalMethod([CallerFilePath] string file = null, [CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
```

At that point, your `InternalMethod()` calls will get the path and line number arguments populated automatically by the compiler. That doesn't help you get the attribute - but it *does* mean you can perform the stack crawl for that call site *once*, and then populate a cache based on that file/line number combination. As a first pass, you could just cache based on `$"{file}:{line}"`, but if you want even higher performance, you'd avoid the string concatenation via a more complicated cache.

Note that the compiler provides the file and line number, so it doesn't matter whether it's a release build, or if the method is inlined, etc.